# Create a "pyramid" matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Say I'm given a symmetric row vector with an odd length where each element is smaller than the next one in the first half of the vector and each element is bigger than the next one in the second half and the middle element is the biggest. (e.g `[1 2 3 2 1]` or `[10 20 50 20 10]`).

I want to create a square matrix where this row vector is its middle row and the equivalent column vector (`v'`) is its middle column and each other row or column is a reduced version of the given vector according to the middle element in this row or column. And when there are no more "original elements" we put `0`.

Examples:

if `v = [1 2 3 2 1]` we get

```
0 0 1 0 0  
0 1 2 1 0  
1 2 3 2 1  
0 1 2 1 0  
0 0 1 0 0
```

if `v = [3 5 3]` we get

```
0 3 0  
3 5 3  
0 3 0
```

What I did so far: I managed to create a matrix with `v` as the middle row and `v'` as the middle column with this code I wrote:

```
s = length(vector);
matrix= zeros(s);
matrix(round(s/2),:) = vector;
matrix(:, round(s/2)) = vector';
```

but got stuck with assigning the other values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A more hands-on approach is to produce your matrix as a mosaic, starting from a `hankel` matrix. For performance comparison, here's a version using the same format as [@Divakar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33756625/5067311):

```
function out=pyramid_hankel(v)

%I suggest checking v here
%it should be odd in length and a palindrome    

i0=ceil(length(v)/2);
v2=v(i0:end);

Mtmp=hankel(v2);
out=zeros(length(v));
out(i0:end,i0:end)=Mtmp;
out(1:i0-1,i0:end)=flipud(Mtmp(2:end,:));
out(:,1:i0-1)=fliplr(out(:,i0+1:end));
```

```
>> pyramid_hankel([1 2 3 2 1])

ans =

     0     0     1     0     0
     0     1     2     1     0
     1     2     3     2     1
     0     1     2     1     0
     0     0     1     0     0
```

For `v=[1 2 3 2 1]` the starting block is `hankel([3 2 1])`, which is

```
ans =

     3     2     1
     2     1     0
     1     0     0
```

From here it should be clear what's happening.

Comment: @Adrian and @AndrasDeak: the `hankel` function uses `bsxfun` internally.

Comment: Oh don't! The way I am using `bsxfun` isn't similar to how `hankel` is implemented using `bsxfun.` AFAIK hankel has `bsxfun(@plus`.

Answer (score 8):

Here's one approach -

```
function out = pyramid(v)

hlen = (numel(v)+1)/2;
updown_vec = [1:(numel(v)+1)/2 (numel(v)-1)/2:-1:1];
upper_part = cumsum(bsxfun(@le,(hlen:-1:1)',updown_vec));  %//'
out = [upper_part ; flipud(upper_part(1:end-1,:))];
out = changem(out,v,updown_vec);
```

Here's another approach, sort of simpler maybe -

```
function out = pyramid_v2(v)

hlen = (numel(v)+1)/2;
updown_vec = [1:(numel(v)+1)/2 (numel(v)-1)/2:-1:1];
mask = bsxfun(@le,([hlen:-1:1 2:hlen])',updown_vec); %//'
M = double(mask);
M(hlen+1:end,:) = -1;
out = changem(cumsum(M).*mask,v,updown_vec);
```

Sample runs -

```
>> v = [1 2 3 2 1];
>> pyramid(v)
ans =
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     1     2     1     0
     1     2     3     2     1
     0     1     2     1     0
     0     0     1     0     0
>> v = [3 5 3];
>> pyramid(v)
ans =
     0     3     0
     3     5     3
     0     3     0

>> v = [99,3,78,55,78,3,99];
>> pyramid(v)
ans =
     0     0     0    99     0     0     0
     0     0    99     3    99     0     0
     0    99     3    78     3    99     0
    99     3    78    55    78     3    99
     0    99     3    78     3    99     0
     0     0    99     3    99     0     0
     0     0     0    99     0     0     0
```

Comment: While my answer seems more easily palatable, do you expect either to be reasonably faster for large problems?

Comment: Because of curiosity i checked yours two methods for calculation speed: @AndrasDeak - 0.055571; Divakar - 0.03777.
But guys! Your mindspeed is killing me - I see this question and already calculate formulas for all necessary diagonals and try to implement it, rubbing my palms... And you already posted your answers which blind my mind it's elegance. I still can't start think in matrix form not in loops form :)

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Appreciate the efforts on benchmarking! So, the one you tested was the `_v2` one, right? Thanks on the your appreciation :)

Comment: @AndrasDeak  I was hoping the `version-2` to be faster, given its a bit simpler and avoids `flipud` and thus appending.

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail_Sam for the feedback!:) Just what I was wondering about. I'm not surprised that Divakar's is faster, I just feel a bit bad for stealing the accept:P Mikhail: for what it's worth, I wouldn't have tried to answer it if I hadn't found `hankel`. I realized that without a necessary built-in, Divakar would beat me hands-down with a `bsxfun`;)

Comment: @Divakar no, I tried `v1`. I have a question: `updown_vec = [1:(numel(v)+1)/2 (numel(v)-1)/2:-1:1];` - `updown_vec` always returns vector same as `v`. What for me use it?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Not when you have `v = [99,3,78,55,78,3,99];` I think. I only use `v` at the end with `changem`.

Comment: @Divakar examining your example I face some problem: look plz at your `v2` method! I think there is mistake in `M(hlen+1,:) = -1;`

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Ah yes need to modify it, as the *leggy* portion of `cumsum(M)` isn't what I expected.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another approach:

```
v = [1 2 3 2 1]; %// symmetric, odd size
m = (numel(v)-1)/2;
w = [0 v(1:m+1)];
t = abs(-m:m);
result = w(max(m+2-bsxfun(@plus, t, t.'),1));
```