# How to create a diamond filled with one in the middle of a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I know the code below :

```
N = 5;
assert(N>1 && mod(N,2)==1);
A = zeros(N);

% diamond mask
N2 = fix(N/2); 
[I,J] = meshgrid(-N2:N2);
mask = (abs(I) + abs(J)) == N2;

% fill with zeros
A(mask) = 1;
```

which transforms matrix `A` to this:

```
A=
    0   0   1   0   0
    0   1   0   1   0
    1   0   0   0   1
    0   1   0   1   0
    0   0   1   0   0
```

But I want the diamond to be filled with 1.
What should I do?

Comment: Seems relevant : [`Create a “pyramid” matrix`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33756154/create-a-pyramid-matrix).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a vectorized approach using [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
Nh = (N+1)/2;
range_vec = [1:Nh Nh-1:-1:1];
out = bsxfun(@plus,range_vec(:),range_vec) > Nh
```

Sample runs -

1) N = 5 :

```
out =
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     1     1     1     0
     1     1     1     1     1
     0     1     1     1     0
     0     0     1     0     0
```

2) N = 9 :

```
out =
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: You are making me have some real feelings for `bsxfun`!

Comment: It has `fun` in it! What more can one expect as *feelings*! ;)

Comment: @erfan You'll fall in love with it very soon.  Divakar made me realize that a long time ago.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`tril`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tril.html) and [`flip`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flip.html) functions:

```
mat = tril(ones(N), round((N-1)/2)) - tril(ones(N), round((-N-1)/2));
out = mat & flip(mat)
```

Odd values of `N`:

```
% N = 5;

out =

     0     0     1     0     0
     0     1     1     1     0
     1     1     1     1     1
     0     1     1     1     0
     0     0     1     0     0
```

Even values of `N`:

```
% N = 4;

out =

     0     1     1     0
     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1
     0     1     1     0
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to return a 1 or a 0 based on the [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) from each array location to the center of your diamond

```
N = 5;
assert(N>1 && mod(N,2)==1);
A = false(N);

[m, n] = size(A);    %dimensions of A
X = floor([m, n]/2);  %floored division gives integer indices of center of array
x = X(1); y = X(2);
radius = m/2;      %half the height gives the radius
for a = 1 : m
    for b = 1 : n
        A(a,b) = abs(a-x)+abs(b-y) <= radius; %test if manhatten distance <= radius  
    end
end
```

This naturally will need editing to suit your particular case... In particular, the center of your diamond can realistically be placed anywhere by modifying `x, y`, and the radius can be either smaller or larger than half the width of the array if you so choose.

Comment: I've taken the liberty in changing your code so that it is proper MATLAB syntax.  Something about seeing a hybrid of C, MATLAB and pseudocode made my eyes twitch.

Comment: @rayryeng haha, yah my only experience with matlab was a one semester course almost 5 years ago.... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `for loop` and fill all diagonals:

```
N = 5;
assert(N>1 && mod(N,2)==1);
A = zeros(N);

% diamond mask
N2 = fix(N/2);
[I,J] = meshgrid(-N2:N2);
for id = 0:N2
    A((abs(I) + abs(J)) == id) = 1;
end
```